# Unable to read Integer in PHP

Tags: php

I am new to PHP, and I got a problem.
I am trying to read number from text file.

http://m3na71jnu5cg5e2.esy.es/FileReadTest.php

```
<?
$fp=fopen("./txt/SampleText.txt","r");
$s=fgets($fp);
$n=(int)$s;
echo $s."<br>";
echo $n."<br>";
fclose($fp);
?>
```

http://m3na71jnu5cg5e2.esy.es/txt/SampleText.txt

```
3
```

and I got

```
3
0
```

what should I do to get integer form of this variable?

Comment: Everything works fine for me, `$s` is a `string` and `$n` an `int`

Comment: The problem may be related to the txt file (line break?) and not the php code.

Comment: I added var_dump($s), and it gave me 'string(4) "3"'.

Comment: It worked when I ignored some bytes from the beginning of the file. The txt file had encoding problem

Answer (score 0):

Try using intval()

```
 $n= intval($s);
```

Comment: Why would the user do that ? An explanation is always welcome.

Comment: as intval is also used to get the integer value of a variable, just in case type casting not work, this will  be helpful

Comment: Perfect, now add that to your answer. PS: the problem isn't related to `intval()`.

Comment: intval() does not work, too. I think I should edit that txt file